# Pulling timecode from videos

Tags: c#, image-processing, video

I'm writing a simple C# app to organize my home photos & videos (they're a mess), and I'm using the original date to organize them.

I know how to pull the date taken from photo files using `System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem`.

How can I do something similar w/ video files, or is this not trivial/possible with C#? The best I have is the `FileInfo.CreationTime`, but as we all know this isn't always accurate.

As a side note, I'm not concerned with the time, just the date, so the timecode at any point during the video would be sufficient.

Comment: Hi, maybe this question and answer will be helpfull? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351713/how-can-i-extract-the-date-from-the-media-created-column-of-a-video-file

Comment: Please tell me that you're not writing w/ instead of 'with'... and even in the title? This website is used by people from all over the world... how would they be able to decode your w/???

Comment: @Sheridan If the SO community is going to be so critical of minor shorthand such as "w/", they should at the very least show the courtesy to point this out a little more constructively.

Comment: No no, that's just my opinion and I *did* give you a valid reason why it's not a good idea to do that.

Comment: @sara Thanks, but it appears that my videos don't have these file-level attributes. I need to somehow access the actual timecode on the video. For example, Media Created is always empty for my videos.

Comment: @JeradRose This 3rd party program should help you out (check source code): http://sourceforge.net/projects/mediainfo/ or use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff384862(v=vs.85).aspx