# Do iOS devices store the GPS location in their .mov files

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, exif

I get all kinds of EXIF data (like location and camera model) easily from images, and I'm trying to replicate this for my .MOV movie files pulled from my iPhone.

I know Apple has this information somewhere because you can see the location in the Photos app, but I don't know how to programmatically access this when looking at .MOV files directly.

In order of preference for my use-case (Python-based personal photo organizer / enrichment):

1. Is this available ideally somewhere in the file (or another file) itself
2. Stored somewhere in iCloud that is queryable / scrapeable
3. Available when building an iOS application (thinking I could build a sync-type app)

To get created date and other properties of MOV files so far, I'm using [hachoir](https://hachoir.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) based on this StackOverflow answer:
[Getting metadata for MOV video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355316/getting-metadata-for-mov-video)

Comment: Where do those MOV files that you are talking about come from?  I get MP4 files from my iPhones.

Comment: This SO thread might help you to get `moov` (movie atom), metadata of your `.mov` with python > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355316/getting-metadata-for-mov-video And this [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/Metadata/Metadata.html) mentions about this key `com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709` contains location of the video.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting metadata for MOV video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355316/getting-metadata-for-mov-video)