# How can I access "Media Created Date" from .mp4 and .jpg files in .net maui?

Tags: .net, metadata, maui, video-processing

I am building an App with .Net Maui and need to access the "medium created date" on .mp4 and .jpg files.

The files are located on my harddrive.

It is not possible to simply access the "file create date", since the files are copys and show a different file create date.

[Medium creation date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV3VD.png)
When inspecting the properties on windows I can see the "medium create date".

[Different file creation date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7axII.png)
As you can see the file create date is compleatly different.

Since this is my first question on Stackoverflow I am sorry in advance if the text should be more clear in any way.
If I should clarify some things, please let me know.

Help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I extract the date from the "Media Created" column of a video file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351713/how-can-i-extract-the-date-from-the-media-created-column-of-a-video-file)

Comment: Sadly not, since there is not method "Folder.GetDetailsOf()" in System.IO. Also it should be crossplatform if possible.
But it is the right direction
Thank you!

Comment: there are numerous other similar questions on this topic

Comment: Yes but i could not find one, that adresses this problem as I have it. Or the answers to the other questions did not help me.

Comment: Some existing solutions should work, *if* done in platform-specific folder `Platforms/Windows`. That is, you won't find a `Maui` solution, but you can find `c# Windows` solutions. I don't know about other platforms.